# Determine if Windows store app has or needs networking capability in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps

I made a script that enumerates store apps, gathers apps SID, and then create firewall rules for all those apps.

Since I can not know what apps somebody may have installed, I cant set specific rules to "block" but all to allow. which is fine since for store apps WFP runs in isolation mode for given user.

The problem is that there is cca. 40+ apps so I end up with some rules which are redundant since not all apps need to connect to internet.

Is there a way to tell if some app needs network access in Powershell?

At the moment I filter out apps like this, but still the result contains non networking apps:

```
Get-AppxPackage -User User -PackageTypeFilter Bundle | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```

Comment: There might be a better way, but you can parse the `AppXManifest.xml` file for each app and look for networking capabilities.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm inactive on this project already, but I do remember looking at this info you mentioned but was not able to find what I needed. when I get back to project I'll take a look again. thanks!